# celery nested task (tasks inside tasks)

Tags: python, django, celery

I wrote 2 update_all_rss task but don't know which one is better. can someone explain it which one should I use?

Info: each task is independent and doesn't need other task result.

It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide me any suggestion to optimize overall performance of these tasks

```
@shared_task(base=BaseTaskWithRetry, task_time_limit=600)
def update_all_rss():
    for xml_link_obj in XmlLink.objects.all().iterator():
        update_single_rss.delay(xml_link_obj)
```

vs

```
@shared_task(base=BaseTaskWithRetry, task_time_limit=600)
def update_all_rss():
    xml_links = list(XmlLink.objects.all().iterator())
    tasks = (update_single_rss.s(xml_link_obj) for xml_link_obj in xml_links)
    result_group = group(tasks)
    result_group()
```

if it helps this is update_single_rss task:

```
@shared_task(base=BaseTaskWithRetry, task_time_limit=120)
def update_single_rss(xml_link_obj):
    channel_qs = Channel.objects.select_related('xml_link').prefetch_related("xml_link__rss_type").filter(
        xml_link=xml_link_obj)
    if channel_qs.exists():
        channel = channel_qs.get()
        channel_parser = channel_parser_mapper(xml_link_obj.channel_parser)
        channel_info = channel_parser(xml_link_obj.xml_link)

        if channel.last_update != channel_info.get("last_update"):
            channel.last_update = channel_info.get("last_update")
            items_parser = items_parser_mapper(xml_link_obj.items_parser)
            items_info = items_parser(xml_link_obj.xml_link)
            ItemClass = item_model_mapper(xml_link_obj.rss_type.name)
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    channel.save()
                    items = (
                        ItemClass(**item, channel=channel)
                        for item in items_info
                        if not ItemClass.objects.filter(guid=item.get("guid")).exists()
                    )
                    ItemClass.objects.bulk_create(items)
            except IntegrityError as e:
                return {"Message": str(e)}

            return {"Message": f"Channel {channel.title} was Updated"}

        return {"Message": f"Channel {channel.title} is Already Updated"}

    return {"Message": f"No channel for {xml_link_obj.xml_link}  Exist"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on your available resources and average time taken by each task. As you put time limit of 120s, I am assuming these are time taking tasks. And if the task depends on any external service, and you expect any unhandled exceptions, better split them as each task gets retried individually without effecting other tasks. Combining them would introduce dependency and retry the whole task.